# My database has a core list of tasks that must be repeated and exported every month without filling the database

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2016

I am using Access 2016 to create a database for my companies Maintenance Schedule. The schedule runs on a 4-weekly rotation. I've made a table and form with which to input all the maintenance tasks. There will be probably around 30 records for each of the four rotations. Our production Manager would use the form to input all the tasks into the table. Then, the engineers, as they completed tasks are to update those tasks by marking them complete and inputting information about potential faults etc etc. So I was thinking I would have a Table kind of like this:

TaskID | Autonumber - Task | Long Text - Rotation | Number - DateCompleted | Date/Time - TaskCompleted | YES/NO - FaultFound | YES/NO - FaultDetails | Long Text - UserCompleted | Short Text

Something like that where our Production Manager would only fill in Task and Rotation fields then the engineer would come back and fill in the rest of the fields. However these tasks are meant to recur and I'll end up with a completed table after the first month. So I'm starting to think there must be a better way to do this with Queries and additional tables but I'm not sure how.

Thank you all for reading and please comment if you have any thoughts. Aside from some Access work in high school (about four years ago) I don't have much experience with the program.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by making two tables:

-First to hold tasks and rotation (entered by manager) and last generated date.

-Second links to task ID, planned date and all other data to be filled by engineer.

A macro is to be created to check last generated date in first table of each item in it (this is basic for tasks only) and generate records in second table with planned date according to rotation required and last generated date and link these records to the original task ID and change last generated date to planned date.

Then you need to run this macro monthly (or even run it whatever number of times to generate orders for all the year.

For engineer to close you need to run query with current data (or date range) to show him the tasks required for today (or for period) and he can close.

Sorry too brief but I hope it helps